# Download Excel File Via Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

I am using the below code invoked via ajax call for create my excel file.On click the download button excel file gets generate at the root location. But I am not able to see the prompt for user to save/save as the file. I can see the response tab of browser where the content of excel are coming. But I want that Save As dialog option to come. Any correction in below code that can solve this issue?

```
            final Date date = new Date();
            final String generateDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
            final String filename = form_name+"-extraction-"+generateDate.toString()+".xls";
            final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
            downloadFile(filename, response);
```

Below is download file method :

```
private void downloadFile(final String fileName, final SlingHttpServletResponse response){
        try {
            final File f = new File(fileName);
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+fileName);
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(f);
            } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final int size = 1024;
            try {
                response.setContentLength(fin.available());
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                ServletOutputStream os = null;

                os = response.getOutputStream();
                int length = 0;
                while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                fin.close();
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (final Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error("ERROR IS ::: {}",ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the disposition type matches "attachment" (case-insensitively),
> this indicates that the recipient should prompt the user to save the
> response locally, rather than process it normally (as per its media
> type).
>
> On the other hand, if it matches "inline" (case-insensitively),
> this    implies default processing.  Therefore, the disposition type
> "inline"    is only useful when it is augmented with additional
> parameters, such    as the filename (see below).
>
> Unknown or unhandled disposition types SHOULD be handled by
> recipients the same way as "attachment" (see also [RFC2183],
> Section 2.8).

So you are forcing the browser to show the file instead of downloading it with your

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+fileName);
```

call. You should use **"attachment"** instead of "inline".

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
```

Read [Use of the Content-Disposition Header Field in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.2) for more info.

Comment: Also I had the issue with Ajax call. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814877/how-to-download-file-via-ajax-with-http-post-i-e-some-info-in-body. So using the hidden field for get call.

Comment: @VivekDhiman there is actually a javascript library that can save files to the disk [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). Or if you will work with big files you can use [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)

Answer (score 0):

If previous searched data output is populated in Excel, you should remove static declarations. For example:

```
private static hasmap hs = new hashmap();
```